# How to copy file to my own computer when backup complete?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When i backup the database complete in SQL Server 2008(On the server),i want to copy the backup file to my local computer from server.(Why have to do this?Because i usually forget to copy the file to my computer when i come home,the database is not the latest)
How can i do? I tried using `xp_cmdshell` but it don't success.

like:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'E:\"Database backup"\bakcpy.bat'
```

I will give the error message tomorrow.

Double click the `bakcpy.bat` it can work successfully.

When i working,my computer and server in the same local network.So i can copy using `xcopy` command.
It is schedule task,i just want to synchronize the database between server sql data with my local computer.Because the server database changed everyday,and i want to backup database from server and copy to compuer in specify time.I don't want to do it manual everytime.

Or maybe i goes the wrong way?Or maybe other better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Is E: referring to a drive on the server or on your local pc? When you execute xp_cmdshell you work on the server and the path has to be on the server side.

Comment: E: is the server path

Comment: Do you get any error message when executing xp_cmdshell?

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have permissions on the destination?

Comment: Questions: How are your local machine and the server connected? You mention "when you get home", which suggests the reason you're copying this is because you will detach your local machine from the network and bring it home with you. What should happen if you disconnect while it's in the middle of copying? Also, what are you doing with this back up once its on your local machine? Maybe there's a better way to move data around. How are your backups being taken? Are you starting that manually or is it on a schedule or something?